# How can check my nodejs error logs which is hosted on azure app service?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

we are using azure app service to host nodejs(backend) app. but we are facing some issues in node app, so we want to see error log in azure app, so how can i check error application log in azure app service ?

Comment: You can use context.log() for Azure functions, and Application Insights for tracing your backend nodejs app. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#write-trace-output-to-logs

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce by deploying a sample nodejs web application to the Azure App Service to check the error logs and deployed successfully.

We have to turn on the **App Service logs** under the **monitoring** in App Service and go to-->**Application Logging** and turn it **on** and set the log levels as per your requirement as shown in the below Screenshot:

[image]

Now go to the **Log streams** under **monitoring** and there we can see the error logs of the application as shown in below image:

[image]